# mysql update from html select option error

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I have a simple select option to update a users information, but it doesnt seem to update it in mysql.

Have a look in my code.

```
session_start();
$UserID = $_GET['id'];
$UserID = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $UserID);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, active FROM users WHERE UserID='$UserID' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $active = $_POST["active"];
    $sql= mysql_query("UPDATE users SET active = '$active' WHERE UserID='$UserID' LIMIT 1");
        $succesMsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
            <i class='fa fa-ban'></i>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>x</button>
            Account gegevens gewijzigd
            </div>";
    $_SESSION['succes'] = $succesMsg;
    header("Location: ".DEFAULT_URL_ADMIN."/user/");
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="active_user" class="standerdForm">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Selecteer</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="active" name="active">
                                          <option value="0" <?php if($row['active'] == 0) {echo 'selected';} ?>>Deactiveren</option>
                                          <option value="1" <?php if($row['active'] == 1) {echo 'selected';} ?>>Activeren</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-footer">

                            <center>
                                <a href="<?=DEFAULT_URL_ADMIN?>/user/" class="btn btn-default marginRight_20">Annuleren</a>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Opslaan">
                            </center>

                            </div>  
                        </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?  Are you getting values for `$_GET['id']`, `$_POST['submit']`, and `$_POST["active"]`?  What's `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, does it have the `id=123` on it?

Comment: Just a note, but this code is *very* unsafe.  A simple POST to your site with `active` set to something like `0' -- ` and your data is gone.  Look up info on MySQLi and parameterized queries.

Comment: Im getting the value of $_GET['id'] because i tried to echo it. But how can i debug and see errors of POST?

Comment: Well, that's good.  What about `$_POST`?  What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Thanks rock, i know, i can filter it.

Comment: How can i see/debug $_POST['submit'], and $_POST["active"]

Comment: Using your browser's dev tools, you can watch the network requests, and it will show you the POST body.  Also, in your PHP, you can do `var_dump($_POST);` to print out all the values passed to PHP via POST.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

to

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```